# Extract email from text file

Tags: regex, linux, grep, debian

I try to extract email from text files with:

```
grep -o ‘[0-9a-zA-Z-_]*@[0-9a-zA-Z-_.]*.[a-zA-Z]*’ infile > outfile.txt
```

But, the result is:

```
grep: Invalid range end
```

I don't know why...

Can someone help ?
Thanks

Comment: You have invalid ranges here: `Z-_`. You need to escape the dash: `Z\-_`. Furthermore the dot `.` is in regex a "match all" character. I guess you want to match it literally, so you also need to escape it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyphen needs to be first or last character in a character class to avoid escaping. If hyphen appears in the middle then it is considered a range.

Try this grep:

```
grep -oE '[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+@[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+' infile > outfile.txt
```

Also your quoted looked suspicious that I have changed as well.

Comment: You need to escape the dot. And i think you need to add `+` after the char class instead of `*`

Comment: Awesome anubhava ! Thanks ! Is it possible to do the same think but with a folder (content many files like infile) ?

Comment: Yes you can do `grep -olE '[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+@[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+' *` to list all the matching emails from various files inside a folder.